# How to Impute Missing Values When Running Machine Learning Binary Classification Using Multiple Text Input Features

Tags: python, machine-learning, missing-data, text-classification, imputation

I spent a lot of time trying to find good answers for my question. When running machine learning binary classification with multiple (say two) text inputs, how do I impute the missing values in the two input features?

I'm just using a simple example to clarify my question. Suppose I'm trying to classify each news article whether it falls into a 'politics' section or not (binary classification). Two input features are 'article contents' and 'title of an article' which consist of texts. In order to address the task in general, I need to pre-process those two inputs and vectorize each input (using countvectorizer or tf-idf and etc). Then you would concatenate two vectorized matrices into one and then choose whatever binary classification method for the later analysis.

Here my question is, how to impute any missing values especially when inputs are texts? I know that there are several ways to do this such as impute the mean value and so on. But this becomes a simple task when an input is numeric such as person's age or income.

To summarize my questions again here:

1. Is there any way to impute the missing values when inputs are texts?
2. One way is to drop a row where it has missing values but I want to keep it alive because one input value might be missing but is not for the other input (just like the Article_ID B & C cases in the below example).

Here is a very simplified example of a data set for clarification. Note that this is a fake data set I came up with just to provide an example.

```
Article_ID    Politics(class)     Contents(input 1)                  Title(input 2)
A              Yes                 The justices heard...             Supreme Court Seems...
B              Yes                 N/A                               U.S. to Begin Offering...
C              No                  The announcement comes as...      N/A
D              Yes                 The two countries said...         Despite Tensions, U.S. ...
E              No                  Movie streaming service is...     Two more seasons renewed...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concatenating two inputs, then some choices that you can use in place of the missing texts:

`zero vector` or

`constant * array(size(vector)) where constant can be (1e-4, 1 / N), N = vocab length or vector length and the array is a vector of ones`

Because whatever vector you use for unknown texts, it is the responsibility of the model to identify its importance in the final prediction.

Comment: you mean I need to multiply the constant to the zero vector? Then the output is going to be zero. Maybe I didn't fully understand could you please give me an example?